# Flask-SocketIO development server works fine but in production it gets stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-socketio, python-watchdog

I am using flask-SocketIO to make an app that updates a GUI whenever a file arrives to a certain directory. Everything seems to work fine when doing flask run on the development server (when using 'flask run') but then when using 'python main.py' it has issues.  This is a simplified version of the culprit:

main.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import watch

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

# the script that looks for new files
watch.watch()

@socketio.on('get stuff')
def receiveResponse():

    import time

    global new_item_arrived
    
    # pause here until a new item  has arrived
    while (new_item_arrived == False): 
        time.sleep(1)
       
    new_item_arrived = False

    # Do Stuff...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

The expected behaviour is the function 'does stuff' when a new file arrives in a certain directory.
I have a python watchdog script that is running looking for these new files. When it does arrive, it changes the value of "new_item_arrived" to be true, which means receiveResponse can go to the next line in the function. When a new item hasn't arrived, the loop just continues on waiting for another item to arrive.

So this works fine when i do 'flask run' but when I do 'python main.py' and a new file arrives, it just gets stuck in this infinite loop. After that, it seems to even freeze up that port or something returning this error:

```
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

And the only way I am able to use my app again is to restart my whole computer.

Also, I should point out that my app does have other functions that use SocketIO but I didn't include them for simplicity and they all work fine. Not sure if it's relevant, but I'm using eventlet as my server.

I'm probably doing missing something obvious to others, but can anyone help?

Comment: Your file watching and the time.sleep function are incompatible with eventlet and gevent. Are you using any of these async frameworks?

Comment: Thanks, you were right. I was using eventlet. I changed time.sleep to socketio.sleep and it solved the problem!